# Alignment in DOJO table

Tags: dojo

I am a beginner in DOJO. I have the following DOJO table.

```javascript
    { name: "I/P Voltage (V)", classes: "title",
        field: "mainsVoltage", width: "80px" },
    { name: "I/P Charging Current (A)", classes: "title",
        field: "gridchargingcurrent", width: "150px" },
    { name: "I/P Frequency (Hz)", classes: "title",
        field: "mainsFreq", width: "120px" }
```

How do I make the units{(v),(A),(Hz)} appear in the center of next line?

Comment: What table you are using? There are currently 3 different implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
{ name: "I/P Voltage (V)", classes: "title",field: "mainsVoltage",  styles: 'text-align: center;', width: "80px" }
```